# How to find out extension (type) of file stored in binary format in database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I have stored files in database in binary format.. Now i want to download these files, i have not stored the name or extension or type of file in any column in the table .. just the binary stream. Can I find out the extension from the binary stream when downloading it? How?

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible for certain type of files that can be recognized by the contents of their first bytes (for example the EXE files have `MZ` as first bytes, the PNG files have `%PNG`), but this is hardly a standard and writing a program that can recognize every possible file type by looking at the contents it is practically impossible. Your best bet is to search informations on the most used files by your customers, create a new column to contains the possible extension and then write a custom program that examines this binary field for its content and then write the extension column (if a match is found). Of course fix the main program that writes the binary contents to fill also the extension column

Comment: I can not create a new column now. It would be fine if i could recognize atleast common file types such as .pdf, .doc, .txt, .jpg , png , .gif , and .zip

Comment: i found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files  but it does not has hex numbers not binary

Comment: Well, this will place a noticeable delay on your code because you have to read these bits and then examine them to find any clue about their real meaning.

Comment: Don't think that article has any value here. If you try to open a PDF file using notepad you will notice that the first 4 bytes are `%PDF` so you need to read these bytes and then conclude what is the appriate extension.

Comment: Could you show the code that stores that data? You need to revert that process to return to the original binary form if you want to show that PDF again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921646/programatically-find-out-a-file-type-by-looking-its-binary-content-possible

Answer (score 0):

If the you don't have enormous amounts of files saved in the db, you could create a backgroundworker class wich itterates through the files in your db, creates a tmp file and stores the needed fileinfo with corresponding ID. You could combine this with Steves answer, your backgroundworker class could try determening the filetype based on the first bytes, and if needed, create a tmp file..